# How to concatenate strings with Velocity Macro

Tags: java, maven, macros, velocity, template-engine

In this maven archetype I am creating, I try to get a string value from Velocity macro with artifactId as the input. The returned string will be assigned as the name of the class. If the artifactId is single word, I capitalize the first letter. If it is a series of strings joined with `.` I take the last word and make first letter uppercase.

```
#macro( capital $str )
#if( $str.contains(".") )
#$str.substring($str.lastIndexOf('.')).substring(1,2).toUppercase()$str.substring($str.lastIndexOf('.')).substring(2)
#else
#$str.substring(0,1).toUppercase()$str.substring(1)
#end
#end

#set( $className = "#capital( $artifactId )" )
#set( $symbol_pound = '#' )
#set( $symbol_dollar = '$' )
#set( $symbol_escape = '\' )
package ${package}.client;

public interface ${className}  {
  //...
}
```

I then installed the archetype with `mvn clean install`. However, in the project generated from this archetype, the class name shows as:

```
public interface    #$str.substring(0,1).toUppercase()yapp
```

It seems like '$str.substring(1)`was correctly executed. However the first part`$str.substring(0,1).toUppercase()` did not work.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you messed the casing of the `toUppercase` method.

Try changing

```
#$str.substring(0,1).toUppercase()$str.substring(1)
```

with

```
#$str.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()$str.substring(1)
```